# Test existence of org "special source editing" buffer

Tags: org-mode

How can I test whether an Org "special source editing" buffer exists?

Answer (score 1):

I use an older version of `org-mode`, but whatever version the O.P. is using probably has the minor-mode named `org-src-mode` which is active when using a special source editing buffer.  I used `mapcar` in this example because I wanted to return a list of all open buffers with the `org-src-mode` having a non-nil value.

```lisp
(delq nil
  (mapcar
    (lambda (buffer)
      (when (with-current-buffer buffer org-src-mode)
        buffer))
    (buffer-list)))
```

---

The doc-string for `org-src-mode` states:

```
"Minor mode for language major mode buffers generated by org.
This minor mode is turned on in two situations:
- when editing a source code snippet with `\\[org-src-mode-map]'.
- When formatting a source code snippet for export with htmlize.
There is a mode hook, and keybindings for `org-edit-src-exit' and
`org-edit-src-save'"
```